# How to use animate.css in css3

Tags: css, animate.css

Can anyone help me please? I don't know how to use [animate.css](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css/blob/master/animate.css).

```css
.original,
.box {
  border-radius: 6px;
}
.original {
  background: #eaeaed;
  border: 1px dashed #cecfd5;
  float: left;
  margin: 12px 15px;
}
.box {
  background: #2db34a;
  height: 95px;
  line-height: 95px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 95px;
}
.spin {
  cursor: pointer;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.spin:hover {
  animation-name: slideDown;
  -webkit-animation-name: slideDown;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
  visibility: visible !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="original">
  <div class="spin">
    <div class="box box-1">Box 1</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looking at [the source of animate.css](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css/blob/master/animate.css), I can see that there is no `slideDown` function. However, there is `slideInDown` and if you use that function, the animation will *work*.

Comment: Better you go through https://github.com/daneden/animate.css/blob/master/README.md or you can use css3 styles by adding another stylesheet. Make sure that, the name of the class/id  does not match with animate.css

Comment: How did this receive an upvote? It literally says 'how to use animate.css'? Please clarify exaclty *what it is that you're looking for**, *what you've tried*, as well as **any further info** you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think that CSS have the property "slideDown".
But you can make somthing like this with CSS trnasition 
http://jsbin.com/hiboyoxoha/1/edit

```css
    .wrapper {
      width: 200px;
      height: 100px;
      background: #44f;
      text-align: center;
      color: #fff;
      line-height: 100px;
      font: 25px arial;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: relative;
    }
    .inner {
      position: absolute;
      height: 100px;
      top: -100px;
      transition: all 0.5s;
      background: #444;
    }
    .wrapper:hover .inner {
      top: 0px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">hover me
    <div class="inner">Hello i am new div</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```